# How does NULLIF of whitespace equate to empty without using TRIM?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, trim, coalesce, nullif

I have a column with nulls, blanks, and one or more white spaces.

NULLS, blanks and white spaces must be converted to INVALID.

To handle this I'm testing:

`COALESCE(NULLIF(COLUMNNAME,''),'INVALID')`

I'm surprised to see this handles the white space. I had thought I'd have to replace `COLUMNNAME` with `TRIM(COLUMNNAME)`.

How does whitespace get automatically handled here? In what scenario would I have had to use TRIM?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: SQL Server trims spaces from the right when comparing things, so `'    '` compares to empty string

Comment: But only spaces, not other whitespace.

Comment: TRIM(COALESCE(COLUMNNAME,'INVALID')) or use RTRIM(LTRIM(COLNAME)) to remove spaces from both sides